# Issue in persistence.xml for Oracle DB

Tags: hibernate, persistence.xml, hibernate-jpa

I am getting below error :org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 77; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not xsd:schema.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
My Persistence.xml counts like below :

```
 <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="jpa-metaservice"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <properties>
        <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1575:sid" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="username" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />

        <!-- Hibernate properties -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />

        <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />
        <class>com.db.solrSearchSvc.model.ModelObjectsorm</class>
        <class>com.db.solrSearchSvc.model.ModelObjectField</class>
        <class>com.db.solrSearchSvc.model.SolrCustomer</class>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: xmlns.jcp.org
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
 
 ... 49 more
 : Line 5 in XML document from URL [file:/C:/Users/1002190/Documents/eclipseWorkspace/sam1/astra-advsearch-services/target/classes/persistence.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 28; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'

Comment: I am using Spring -Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE on Tomcat 9. Kindly help with persistence.xml schema location so that I could come over this issue .

Comment: `Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.'`

Comment: Could you please provide full stack trace and and full `persistence.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

you should add below dependency to your pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```